# Overload the actions inside controller : asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

> Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
>
> LogOn - Action.
>
> Home - Controller.

So It will create the Url like = Home/LogOn .

But If I have action `LogOn(String s )`  , `LogOn(int i)` inside the controller `Home` and both are `HttpPost` ,
Then which one action raise at that time . means right now it is giving exception :

> "ambiguous between the
>
> following action methods"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have 2 actions with the same name inside the same controller. The only way for this to work is to make one of the 2 actions accessible only with `[HttpPost]`:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(int i)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(string s)
{
    ...
}
```

Now when you submit the form it will invoke the second action. And when you type `/home/logon` in your browser address bar (using GET verb) it will execute the first action to probably render the LogOn form.

Comment: It means inside One Controller there is only two Actions with the same name having HttpGet and HttpPost , not more then that with same name .

Comment: @ManojPant not exactly you can have overloads